# enumeration of elements for lists within lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a collection of files (kind of like CSV, but no commas) with data arranged like the following:

```
RMS  ResNum  Scores  Rank
30      1       44     5
12      1       99     2
2       1       60     1
1.5     1       63     3 
12      2       91     4
2       2       77     3
```

I'm trying to write a script that enumerates for me and gives an integer as the output.  I want it to count how many times we get a value of RMS below 3 AND a score above 51.   Only if both these criteria are met should it add 1 to our count.

HOWEVER,  the tricky part is that for any given "ResNum" it cannot add 1 multiple times.  In other words, I want to sub-group the data by ResNum then decide 1 or 0 on whether or not those two criteria are met within that group.

So right now it would give as an output as 3, whereas I want it to display 2 instead. Since ResNum 1 is being counted twice here (two rows meet the criteria).

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("*")
file_list = sorted(file_list)

for input_file in file_list:

    masterlist = []

    opened_file = open(input_file,'r')

    count = 0

    for line in opened_file:

            data = line.split()

            templist = []

            templist.append(float(data[0]))     #RMS

            templist.append(int(data[1]))      #ResNum

            templist.append(float(data[2]))     #Scores

            templist.append(float(data[3]))   #Rank

            masterlist.append(templist)
```

then here comes the part that needs modification (I think)

```
for placement in masterlist:

            if placement[0] <3 and placement[2] >51.0:

                    count += 1

    print input_file
    print count
    count = 0
```

Comment: In you example data, 3 rows meet the criteria. RMS 2, 1.5 and 2 (last one)

Answer (score 0):

Choose you data structures carefully to make your life easier.

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("*")
file_list = sorted(file_list)
grouper = {}
for input_file in file_list:
    with open(input_file) as f:
        grouper[input_file] = set()
        for line in f:
            rms, resnum, scores, rank = line.split()
            if int(rms) < 3 and float(scores) > 53:
                grouper[input_file].add(float(resnum))

for input_file, group in grouper.iteritems():
    print input_file
    print len(group)
```

This creates a dictionary of sets. The key of this dictionary is the file-name. The values are sets of the `ResNum`s, added only when your condition holds. Since sets don't have repeated elements, the size of your set (`len`) will give you the right count of the number of times your condition was met, per `ResNum`, per file.